# is it safe to leave out "if __name__ == '__main__'" statement for multiprocessing in python under unix?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to implement a felxible pipeline in python, that i have split up into several modules.
Each of these modules can be used as a standalone tool, but they may also sometimes have to import functions from each other.
I have placed general simple functions, that are used frequently by multiple of these modules, into a "misc" module that is imported by all of the other modules when needed.

Now, each of these modules may want to run some functions in parallel using multiprocessing (usually calling some external tools).
So i have created a general "run_parallel" function that takes a list of functions and corresponding arguments as arguments, determines the priority of each and distributes the avaiable cores over them accordingly, and then runs these functions in parallel using multiprocessing and starmap().

Now i think this function could nicely be placed in the "misc" module and could just be imported when any of the other functions need to run jobs in parallel. However, if i follow the (apparently) general rule to *always* use the `if __name__ ==  '__main__` statement for this, that means I can't import this function and reuse it in multiple modules. I never fully understood this requirement, but it does seem to have something to do with windows, specifically? My pipeline will work ONLY under unix.

Does that mean I MUST implement this "run_parallel" method seperately for each of my modules?
Or can i just safely leave it away, if my code only is meant to run under linux/unix environments?

EDIT: I realize now i just completely misunderstood the usage of this statement in the tutorials and usage examples for multiprocessing. I thought, for some reason it was required also within any function that uses something from multiprocessing (and have always been confused about why that would be). But in these examples they were also only protecting the part of the example code that would call that function, preventing it from automatically being called on every import (not preventing than function to be importet at all, as i thought). Total misunderstanding!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I had trouble trying to understand you - but it seems like you're confusing concepts. For starting:

Everything under the `if __name__ == "__main__" only executes when the module is called directly, but not when it's imported.

Comment: "that means I can't import this function and reuse it in multiple modules." No, that is not what it means at all. It means when you *reuse it somewhere* it has to be called in code that is guarded.

Comment: Question for @jov14: would you lose anything by including the `if __name__ == '__main__': ...` anyway? I think not.

Comment: @Nicolas Martinez @ Justin Ezequiel: That is exactly my problem. I have a function that takes other functions and runs them in parallel. It is a function that needs to be imported, because that way, it can be applied for a lot of differnt functions from different modules. However, It can't be imported because of the ```if __name__ =='__main__':```statement (or rather: it CAN be imported, but then it does not run). That is highly inconvenient, and my question is, is this restriction strictly necessary? And why?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I am sorry, what does "code that is guarded" mean? could you give me have an example for such an import? My problem is: this function apparently should include this statement. Therefore it will not be run unless it is called from within the same module. Which means i can't import it and instead i have to write the same code for this function in every module, no?

Comment: Ah okok, i apparently misunderstood the fact that examples and tutorials about python multiprocessing always stress this statement so much. I understand that it simply marks code that shouId only run when the module is called directly, and had gotten the impression that any function calling multiprocessing was required to be marked this way, preventing it from being imported. Thanks, i guess i got a little bit less dumb today

Comment: @jov14 sorry, the whole `if __name__ ==  '__main__':` idiom is sometimes referred to as "being guarded", because you are guarding against the execution of the code in that block when the module is imported. I'm not sure what you don't understand, exactly, but you have some module `foo` where the functions use multiprocessing. You then import that module `import foo` in `bar.py`, let's say, and *there* in the guarded code you run `foo.some_function()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a script or import a module, python executes all of the code written at module level. In the case of a function like

```
def foo():
    pass
```

"execution" only means to assign the newly compiled function object to a variable called "foo". These things do not need to be protected by a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. You only need to be concerned about code that performs an action, such as code that *calls* `foo()`.

The top level script called to start a python program is called `"__main__"`. Modules that you import are not called `"__main__"` and a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block is pointless. What is important is that modules be import-safe. That is, it should always be safe to import a module without it doing anything beyond initialization. The actions of a module should always be inside functions or classes that are called from other places.

The top level script is different, it has to actually run the program. `if __name__ == "__main__":` is used to make the top level script import safe. That doesn't matter (at least for multiprocessing) for forking systems like Unix. But Windows needs to spawn a new process and import the top level script - and that import needs to safe, it can't re-execute the program itself.

Although you don't need this protection on Unix, modules should always be import-safe. And its a good discipline for top level scripts, too. Why limit code execution when you don't have to?

A decent recipe for scripts is

```
def main()
    do all the things
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    retcode = main()
    exit(retcode)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for clarifying. I did actually understand this function of that statement. But i also got under the impression somehow that any function using multiprocessing needs that statement also, because most examples on how to use multiprocessing stressed this statement so prominently. I see now that i probably misinterpreted this.

Comment: Right, functions don't need it and neither do imported modules. Only the top level script that executes the program and calls the function.